# How does bash backslash two-level escaping behave?

Tags: bash, shell, escaping

Bash backslash escapes any character that follows:

```
$ echo "Result: \e"
Result:
$ echo "Result: \\"
Result: \
```

However Bash backslash seems to have a two-levels escaping system:

```
$ echo "Result: \\e"
Result:
```

If I understand it correctly, in the previous example the first backslash escapes the second one, which results in a backslash. This backslash then escapes the next character, `e`.

If `e` is escaped, why is the last `"` not escaped? I would expect the following to escape it, however the result is a simple escaping:

```
$ echo "Result: \\"
Result: \
```

How does this selective two-level escaping behave, and what triggers it?

Comment: `echo "Result: \\e"` yeilds `Result: \e`, not what you have indicated.  I am on Linux.  What OS are you trying this on?  See this post as well: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189451/echo-bash-backslash-escape-behavior-is-it-evaluated-backwards

Comment: I am trying this on Windows 10. However, I am using bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The escape character \e you mention corresponds to the keyboard "Esc" key, not a backslash escape. For getting an "Esc" key character, you must use:

```
echo $'\e'
```

You get UTF-8 char 0x001b which is the "Esc" key code ([UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)).

Check Bash's manual page by running `man bash` and then search for "\e" by typing:

```
/\\e
```

`/` is for finding, and `\\e` is for escaping the `\` and getting `\e`.

In Bash, the backslash means "literal". Below are the results I get from bash 4.4.20 in GNU/Linux Mint with some comments.

```
$ echo "Result: e"
Result: e
$ echo "Result: \e"
Result: \e
```

I have doubts about this result (*).

```
$ echo "Result: \\e"
Result: \e
```

Here we said: a literal \ and and e. That's what it printed.

```
$ echo "Result: \\\e"
Result: \\e
```

Here we said: a literal \ and an escape character.

```
$ echo "Result: \\\\e"
Result: \\e
```

Two literal \'s.

```
$ echo "Result: \\\\\e"
Result: \\\e
```

Two literal \'s and an escape character.

```
$ echo "Result: \\\\\\e"
Result: \\\e
```

And so on.

The \e does not work as an escape character in echo, you have to use `\`.

(*) This result may correspond to `echo $"\e"`. According to the man page:

> A  double-quoted  string preceded by a dollar sign ($"string") will
>   cause the string to be translated according to the current locale.

In Bash I get:

```
$ echo $"\e"
\e
```